# Where is docs directory of django-sphinxdoc

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I would like to use **django-sphinxdoc** package for documentation inside my django project. There is a site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinxdoc/ of this package and it says:

> The Documentation can be found in the docs/ directory.

I can't find the directory. Could someone tell where it can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that comment is referencing the [`docs/` directory of the django-sphinxdoc source tree](https://bitbucket.org/ssc/django-sphinxdoc/src/604d6674c273/docs/?at=default) though the actual docs seems to be in [`docs/ref/`](https://bitbucket.org/ssc/django-sphinxdoc/src/604d6674c2733588d96f33688d91e3bd48e442f9/docs/ref/?at=default).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I should improve my experience with bitbucket source files.